# Hack/Mine error when launching in Technic Launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

I am using the "new" Technic Launcher and one day upon trying to launch Hack/Mine the technic launcher would dissapear, and then reappear. I selected "show console" and tried again. This yielded the following error message:

```
[B#439] Analytics Response [runLauncher]: 200
[B#439] {"accessToken":"4dd663750a334f1b93f0fc6c2ca2cad2","clientToken":"2b9c15a6-b3ca-46ba-a712-fb68b35fee59","selectedProfile":{"id":"02f9faa3034c465f8871164d06118694","name":"pianist1119"}}
[B#439] Pack: hexplore-it Image Download Worker Calculated MD5: f07c192f761a8561f7205ce81551f1d8 Required MD5: 5e0dde17fb3e1ed12a3483bc7256126e
[B#439] Starting download of http://cdn.technicpack.net/platform/pack-backgrounds/226213.png?1409016327, with 3 tries remaining
[B#439] Pack: hexplore-it Image Download Worker Calculated MD5: 802b6c76382501e25f4e835056de3947 Required MD5: 168b9ff86941fa5df7d0fb5fd1708a8a
[B#439] Starting download of http://cdn.technicpack.net/platform/pack-logos/226213.png?1409016327, with 3 tries remaining
[B#439] Pack: hexplore-it Image Download Worker Calculated MD5: f07c192f761a8561f7205ce81551f1d8 Required MD5: 5e0dde17fb3e1ed12a3483bc7256126e
[B#439] Starting download of http://cdn.technicpack.net/platform/pack-backgrounds/226213.png?1409016327, with 3 tries remaining
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='gigatech-solder', display_name='GigaTech Solder', url='null', icon_md5='a5ea4c8fa53984c911a1b52ca31bc008', logo_md5='5d79fe101f698670c6e78b8ab3d39c45', background_md5='6459ea4e4efaacca66092796a6e58755', recommended='1.2.3', latest='1.2.3', builds=[1.1.10, 1.1.10.staff, 1.1.11, 1.1.11.staff, 1.2, 1.2.staff, 1.2.1, 1.2.1.staff, 1.2.2, 1.2.2.staff, 1.2.3, 1.2.3.staff], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@39ab1c32}, name='gigatech-solder', platform=true, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\gigatech-solder'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=PlatformPackInfo{name='pianist1119s-mod', displayName='Pianist1119's Mod', url='https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls7judwow8x85ti/modpack.zip?dl=1', icon=null, logo=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@19f30f89, background=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@3bab1723, minecraft='1.6.4', forge='null', version='1.0', solder='', forceDir=false}, name='pianist1119s-mod', platform=true, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\pianist1119s-mod'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='gigatech-solder', display_name='GigaTech Solder', url='null', icon_md5='a5ea4c8fa53984c911a1b52ca31bc008', logo_md5='5d79fe101f698670c6e78b8ab3d39c45', background_md5='6459ea4e4efaacca66092796a6e58755', recommended='1.2.3', latest='1.2.3', builds=[1.1.10, 1.1.10.staff, 1.1.11, 1.1.11.staff, 1.2, 1.2.staff, 1.2.1, 1.2.1.staff, 1.2.2, 1.2.2.staff, 1.2.3, 1.2.3.staff], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@39ab1c32}, name='gigatech-solder', platform=true, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\gigatech-solder'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=PlatformPackInfo{name='pianist1119s-mod', displayName='Pianist1119's Mod', url='https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls7judwow8x85ti/modpack.zip?dl=1', icon=null, logo=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@19f30f89, background=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@3bab1723, minecraft='1.6.4', forge='null', version='1.0', solder='', forceDir=false}, name='pianist1119s-mod', platform=true, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\pianist1119s-mod'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=null, name='null', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='null'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='vanilla', display_name='Vanilla', url='', icon_md5='aefa89c377dcb217fdf99988f6e25b8f', logo_md5='60d2a003a1d54d6bac98160cf0daadef', background_md5='f704462da01de4f16f336fac20e68426', recommended='1.7.10', latest='1.7.10', builds=[1.4.7, 1.4.6, 1.4.5, 1.3.2, 1.2.3, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.2, 1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.9, 1.7.10], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='vanilla', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\vanilla'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=null, name='null', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='null'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=PlatformPackInfo{name='pianist1119s-mod', displayName='Pianist1119's Mod', url='https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls7judwow8x85ti/modpack.zip?dl=1', icon=null, logo=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@19f30f89, background=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@3bab1723, minecraft='1.6.4', forge='null', version='1.0', solder='', forceDir=false}, name='pianist1119s-mod', platform=true, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\pianist1119s-mod'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='gigatech-solder', display_name='GigaTech Solder', url='null', icon_md5='a5ea4c8fa53984c911a1b52ca31bc008', logo_md5='5d79fe101f698670c6e78b8ab3d39c45', background_md5='6459ea4e4efaacca66092796a6e58755', recommended='1.2.3', latest='1.2.3', builds=[1.1.10, 1.1.10.staff, 1.1.11, 1.1.11.staff, 1.2, 1.2.staff, 1.2.1, 1.2.1.staff, 1.2.2, 1.2.2.staff, 1.2.3, 1.2.3.staff], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@39ab1c32}, name='gigatech-solder', platform=true, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\gigatech-solder'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=PlatformPackInfo{name='hexplore-it', displayName='Hexplore-It', url='http://repo.hexplore-it.com/Hexplore-It_ModPack_v1.06.zip', icon=null, logo=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@63a8086d, background=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@7eeb03e8, minecraft='1.6.4', forge='null', version='1.06', solder='', forceDir=false}, name='hexplore-it', platform=true, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\hexplore-it'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='tekkitmain', display_name='Tekkit', url='http://www.technicpack.net/tekkit', icon_md5='1dd87c03268a7144411bb8cbe8bf7326', logo_md5='175523449f470a05bf4a32dfa3c48b0c', background_md5='f39ae618809383451f6832e4d2a738fe', recommended='1.2.9e', latest='1.2.10c', builds=[1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.1.10, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.5b, 1.2.5c, 1.2.5d, 1.2.6, 1.2.6b, 1.2.7, 1.2.7b, 1.2.8, 1.2.8b, 1.2.8c, 1.2.8d, 1.2.8e, 1.2.9, 1.2.9b, 1.2.9c, 1.2.9d, 1.2.9e, 1.2.10, 1.2.10c], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='tekkitmain', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\tekkitmain'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='hexxit', display_name='Hexxit', url='null', icon_md5='fb51fd408d5d3bc7eba8d9a820ab555c', logo_md5='1426f5b19df42eab2cabbaa34823c8c9', background_md5='a99b0c0eb00ac657d29eb9e1f9086033', recommended='1.0.10', latest='2.0.1c', builds=[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.0.10, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.1b, 2.0.1c], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='hexxit', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\hexxit'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='attack-of-the-bteam', display_name='Attack of the B-Team', url='null', icon_md5='', logo_md5='', background_md5='', recommended='1.0.12a', latest='1.0.13c', builds=[1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.6a, 1.0.7, 1.0.7a, 1.0.8, 1.0.9b, 1.0.9c, 1.0.10, 1.0.10a, 1.0.10b, 1.0.11, 1.0.11a, 1.0.12, 1.0.12a, 1.0.13b, 1.0.13c], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='attack-of-the-bteam', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\attack-of-the-bteam'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='tekkitlite', display_name='Tekkit Lite', url='http://www.technicpack.net/tekkit-lite', icon_md5='aefa89c377dcb217fdf99988f6e25b8f', logo_md5='4dc44bd7a08fa76f3e619587f189f8eb', background_md5='5a4592cb38f9bf0ca76b0667c6196b0b', recommended='0.6.5', latest='0.6.5', builds=[0.5.9, 0.5.8.1, 0.5.7, 0.5.6, 0.5.5, 0.5.4, 0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4, 0.6.5], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='tekkitlite', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\tekkitlite'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='voltz', display_name='Voltz', url='http://www.technicpack.net/voltz', icon_md5='820ad79798bf8fce3317ad7bb6302384', logo_md5='57bab00b470b738898084b29b541a3e7', background_md5='e9111ee2909af2bc0fa78a50812b1c0a', recommended='2.0.4', latest='3.1.2', builds=[1.0.13, 1.0.12, 1.0.11, 1.0.10, 1.0.9, 1.0.8, 1.0.7, 1.0.6, 1.0.5, 1.0.4, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.4, 3.0.0, 3.0.0b, v3.0.0c, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='voltz', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\voltz'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='bigdig', display_name='Big Dig', url='null', icon_md5='4bbc148086691db988242f6bcd858dee', logo_md5='16bc208163966b47f44b037c31297e31', background_md5='bfd4cc5218492c5bd230e343e677cbfb', recommended='1.3.9', latest='1.3.13', builds=[1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.3.10, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='bigdig', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\bigdig'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='tekkit', display_name='Tekkit Classic', url='http://www.technicpack.net/tekkit-classic', icon_md5='aefa89c377dcb217fdf99988f6e25b8f', logo_md5='b94c1ec5d65e7dac4c191c597f2e7cab', background_md5='41cf738eacf5db3cfd7e3eb505357c6e', recommended='3.1.2', latest='3.1.3', builds=[3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.5, 3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.0], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='tekkit', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\tekkit'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='yogbox', display_name='Yogbox', url='', icon_md5='a78ce251f21dba504fa97b5ba724f305', logo_md5='5249adc2b683784089759e28bc37e01d', background_md5='9acbe5a823ecdb39aea88114a7923f7f', recommended='1.2.1', latest='1.2.5', builds=[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.5], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='yogbox', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\yogbox'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='hackslashmine', display_name='Hack Slash Mine', url='http://www.technicpack.net/hackslashmine', icon_md5='7225c0f609c2fa3ba934c2bff296bdfb', logo_md5='f3497f0c1804cbf693c9ce863d5eea56', background_md5='d39a840f9033993b050167a83b3e9f3a', recommended='0.6.4.6', latest='0.6.4.6', builds=[0.6.0, 0.4, 0.6.4, 0.6.4.1, 0.6.4.2, 0.6.4.3, 0.6.4.4, 0.6.4.5f, 0.6.4.6], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='hackslashmine', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\hackslashmine'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='vanilla', display_name='Vanilla', url='', icon_md5='aefa89c377dcb217fdf99988f6e25b8f', logo_md5='60d2a003a1d54d6bac98160cf0daadef', background_md5='f704462da01de4f16f336fac20e68426', recommended='1.7.10', latest='1.7.10', builds=[1.4.7, 1.4.6, 1.4.5, 1.3.2, 1.2.3, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.2, 1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.9, 1.7.10], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='vanilla', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\vanilla'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=null, name='null', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='null'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=PlatformPackInfo{name='pianist1119s-mod', displayName='Pianist1119's Mod', url='https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls7judwow8x85ti/modpack.zip?dl=1', icon=null, logo=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@19f30f89, background=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@3bab1723, minecraft='1.6.4', forge='null', version='1.0', solder='', forceDir=false}, name='pianist1119s-mod', platform=true, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\pianist1119s-mod'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='gigatech-solder', display_name='GigaTech Solder', url='null', icon_md5='a5ea4c8fa53984c911a1b52ca31bc008', logo_md5='5d79fe101f698670c6e78b8ab3d39c45', background_md5='6459ea4e4efaacca66092796a6e58755', recommended='1.2.3', latest='1.2.3', builds=[1.1.10, 1.1.10.staff, 1.1.11, 1.1.11.staff, 1.2, 1.2.staff, 1.2.1, 1.2.1.staff, 1.2.2, 1.2.2.staff, 1.2.3, 1.2.3.staff], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@39ab1c32}, name='gigatech-solder', platform=true, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\gigatech-solder'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=PlatformPackInfo{name='pianist1119s-mod', displayName='Pianist1119's Mod', url='https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls7judwow8x85ti/modpack.zip?dl=1', icon=null, logo=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@19f30f89, background=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.Resource@3bab1723, minecraft='1.6.4', forge='null', version='1.0', solder='', forceDir=false}, name='pianist1119s-mod', platform=true, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\pianist1119s-mod'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=null, name='null', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='null'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='vanilla', display_name='Vanilla', url='', icon_md5='aefa89c377dcb217fdf99988f6e25b8f', logo_md5='60d2a003a1d54d6bac98160cf0daadef', background_md5='f704462da01de4f16f336fac20e68426', recommended='1.7.10', latest='1.7.10', builds=[1.4.7, 1.4.6, 1.4.5, 1.3.2, 1.2.3, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.2, 1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.9, 1.7.10], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='vanilla', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\vanilla'}
[B#439] InstalledPack{info=SolderPackInfo{name='hackslashmine', display_name='Hack Slash Mine', url='http://www.technicpack.net/hackslashmine', icon_md5='7225c0f609c2fa3ba934c2bff296bdfb', logo_md5='f3497f0c1804cbf693c9ce863d5eea56', background_md5='d39a840f9033993b050167a83b3e9f3a', recommended='0.6.4.6', latest='0.6.4.6', builds=[0.6.0, 0.4, 0.6.4, 0.6.4.1, 0.6.4.2, 0.6.4.3, 0.6.4.4, 0.6.4.5f, 0.6.4.6], solder=net.technicpack.launchercore.restful.solder.Solder@42f05f7b}, name='hackslashmine', platform=false, build='recommended', directory='%MODPACKS%\hackslashmine'}
[B#439] Analytics Response [installModpack]: 200
[B#439] Starting download of http://mirror.technicpack.net/Technic/mods/basemods/basemods-hackslashmine-v0.6.4.6.zip, with 3 tries remaining
[B#439] Expected MD5: 8bac52a7f6e22c0f3326a57c15766c2d Calculated MD5: 8bac52a7f6e22c0f3326a57c15766c2d
[B#439] Starting download of http://mirror.technicpack.net/Technic/version/1.2.3/1.2.3.json, with 3 tries remaining
[B#439] Expected MD5: 12f6c4b1bdcc63f029e3c088a364b8e4 Calculated MD5: 12f6c4b1bdcc63f029e3c088a364b8e4
[B#439] Expected MD5: 1372bd4823bb1ef61e7db6724f601150 Calculated MD5: 1372bd4823bb1ef61e7db6724f601150
[B#439] Expected MD5: d21c2a06a4e6b175aa01e328f38a1182 Calculated MD5: d21c2a06a4e6b175aa01e328f38a1182
[B#439] Expected MD5: cc07d371f79dc4ed2239e1101ae06313 Calculated MD5: cc07d371f79dc4ed2239e1101ae06313
[B#439] Expected MD5: f60976b19661c849c5c87433045a9885 Calculated MD5: f60976b19661c849c5c87433045a9885
[B#439] Expected MD5: ce74486a7687ad7ea91dcc1fcd6977b8 Calculated MD5: ce74486a7687ad7ea91dcc1fcd6977b8
[B#439] Expected MD5: 6a0eeaf3451ed9646b7d61a9dd8b86cc Calculated MD5: 6a0eeaf3451ed9646b7d61a9dd8b86cc
[B#439] Expected MD5: 30e99b9386040f387fd94c26c1ac64d3 Calculated MD5: 30e99b9386040f387fd94c26c1ac64d3
[B#439] Expected MD5: b168b014be0186d9e95bf3d263e3a129 Calculated MD5: b168b014be0186d9e95bf3d263e3a129
[B#439] Expected MD5: b168b014be0186d9e95bf3d263e3a129 Calculated MD5: b168b014be0186d9e95bf3d263e3a129
[B#439] Running C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\javaw.exe -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\hackslashmine\bin\natives -Dfml.core.libraries.mirror=http://mirror.technicpack.net/Technic/lib/fml/%s -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\hackslashmine -cp C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\cache\net\technicpack\legacywrapper\1.2.1\legacywrapper-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\cache\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\cache\org\ow2\asm\asm-all\4.1\asm-all-4.1.jar;C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\cache\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\cache\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\cache\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.0\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\cache\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.0\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\hackslashmine\bin\modpack.jar;C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\hackslashmine\bin\minecraft.jar net.technicpack.legacywrapper.Launch pianist1119 token:4dd663750a334f1b93f0fc6c2ca2cad2:02f9faa3034c465f8871164d06118694 --gameDir C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\hackslashmine --assetsDir C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\assets\virtual\legacy --title Hack Slash Mine --icon C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\.technic\assets/packs/hackslashmine/icon.png
[B#439] Analytics Response [runModpack]: 200
[B#439]  [Ljava.lang.String;@7229724f
[B#439]  Creating new syntaxHighlight.txt...
[B#439]  Failed to load class by identifier 'java.lang.String'!
[B#439]  spellscript.ScopeException: Scope Exception: class java.lang.String hasn't implemented all its inherited abstract methods.
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.compileMethodInfo(ClassInfo.java:599)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.JavaToSS.getClassInfo(JavaToSS.java:282)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.JavaToSS$1.getClassInfo(JavaToSS.java:59)
[B#439]     at spellscript.resolvetype.ClassType.isAssignableFromNonRange(ClassType.java:143)
[B#439]     at spellscript.resolvetype.ResolveType.isAssignableFrom(ResolveType.java:181)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.FunctionInfo.assertIsOverridableBy(FunctionInfo.java:283)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.tryToOverrideMethodOnMe(ClassInfo.java:368)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.tryToOverrideMethod(ClassInfo.java:381)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.tryToOverrideMethodOnSuperTypes(ClassInfo.java:389)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.tryToOverrideMethod(ClassInfo.java:381)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.tryToOverrideMethodOnSuperTypes(ClassInfo.java:389)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.makeFunction(ClassInfo.java:449)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.JavaToSS.getClassInfo(JavaToSS.java:267)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.searchClassPath(ScopeMap.java:269)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.getClassInfo(ScopeMap.java:246)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.importJavaLang(ScopeMap.java:87)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.<init>(ScopeMap.java:56)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.<init>(ScopeMap.java:69)
[B#439]     at spellscript.SpellscriptPackageBuilder.buildPackage(SpellscriptPackageBuilder.java:124)
[B#439]     at spellscript.Globals.<clinit>(Globals.java:521)
[B#439]     at spellscript.hooks.SSUtils.initializeSpellscript(SSUtils.java:33)
[B#439]     at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:388)
[B#439]     at n.<init>(SourceFile:33)
[B#439]     at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftApplet.init(MinecraftApplet.java:36)
[B#439]     at net.minecraft.Launcher.init(Launcher.java:127)
[B#439]     at net.technicpack.legacywrapper.Frame.runGame(Frame.java:94)
[B#439]     at net.technicpack.legacywrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:17)
[B#439]  java.lang.NullPointerException
[B#439]     at spellscript.resolvetype.ClassType.isAssignableFromNonRange(ClassType.java:145)
[B#439]     at spellscript.resolvetype.ResolveType.isAssignableFrom(ResolveType.java:181)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.FunctionInfo.assertIsOverridableBy(FunctionInfo.java:283)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.tryToOverrideMethodOnMe(ClassInfo.java:368)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.tryToOverrideMethod(ClassInfo.java:381)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.tryToOverrideMethodOnSuperTypes(ClassInfo.java:389)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.tryToOverrideMethod(ClassInfo.java:381)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.tryToOverrideMethodOnSuperTypes(ClassInfo.java:389)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ClassInfo.makeFunction(ClassInfo.java:449)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.JavaToSS.getClassInfo(JavaToSS.java:267)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.searchClassPath(ScopeMap.java:269)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.getClassInfo(ScopeMap.java:246)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.importJavaLang(ScopeMap.java:87)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.<init>(ScopeMap.java:56)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.<init>(ScopeMap.java:69)
[B#439]     at spellscript.SpellscriptPackageBuilder.buildPackage(SpellscriptPackageBuilder.java:124)
[B#439]     at spellscript.Globals.<clinit>(Globals.java:521)
[B#439]     at spellscript.hooks.SSUtils.initializeSpellscript(SSUtils.java:33)
[B#439]     at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:388)
[B#439]     at n.<init>(SourceFile:33)
[B#439]     at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftApplet.init(MinecraftApplet.java:36)
[B#439]     at net.minecraft.Launcher.init(Launcher.java:127)
[B#439]     at net.technicpack.legacywrapper.Frame.runGame(Frame.java:94)
[B#439]     at net.technicpack.legacywrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:17)
[B#439]  java.lang.NullPointerException
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.importJavaLang(ScopeMap.java:87)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.<init>(ScopeMap.java:56)
[B#439]     at spellscript.scope.ScopeMap.<init>(ScopeMap.java:69)
[B#439]     at spellscript.SpellscriptPackageBuilder.buildPackage(SpellscriptPackageBuilder.java:124)
[B#439]     at spellscript.Globals.<clinit>(Globals.java:521)
[B#439]     at spellscript.hooks.SSUtils.initializeSpellscript(SSUtils.java:33)
[B#439]     at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:388)
[B#439]     at n.<init>(SourceFile:33)
[B#439]     at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftApplet.init(MinecraftApplet.java:36)
[B#439]     at net.minecraft.Launcher.init(Launcher.java:127)
[B#439]     at net.technicpack.legacywrapper.Frame.runGame(Frame.java:94)
[B#439]     at net.technicpack.legacywrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:17)
[B#439]  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

so far i have tried to delete and reinstall hack/mine in the modpacks folder, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated :) I am currently using java 1.8.0_11 to run the technic launcher

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your log, it seems that your Java installation did not load all the Java library files properly. And when it called upon a function, it just errored. All I can suggest is that you reinstall Java [here](http://www.java.com) and wipe all your Technic files, which should be in C:\Users[Your username]\AppData\.technic\

EDIT: Also, this isn't the place to post error logs. They should be posted [here](http://forums.technicpack.net/).

Comment: okay thanks for the response :). I will probably copy this to the technic forums. I can try backing up my one important world on another modpack and wiping and reinstalling technic. Im using a fresh install of java 1.8.0_11 so im sure that isnt a problem, seeing as I literally installed it yesterday.

Comment: I thank thee, I never considered completely reinstalling Technic Launcher, so I did that. Then I installed java 1.7.0_67 alongside my other 2 versions, whipped up a batch file and voila! Hack/Mine completely functional!!

Answer (score -1):

downgrade to java 7 it will make it work